# How to load the content of the page when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a notification page which has to be loaded while page loading i have tested it with set timeout its working well but it is killing the bandwidth and taking website off line so i want that to be loaded when page load is completed but its not working here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadLog(){
  alert('Ok');
  $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
            url: "notify.php",
            cache: false,
        data :{ },
            success: function(data){
          //alert(data);
          //console.log('my message' + data);
          $("#notifications").empty();
          $("#notifications").append(data);
                 //console.log(html);
            },
        });
};

$(document).ready(loadLog);
</script>
```

Its working alright if i use in at this way.

```
setInterval (loadLog, 2500);
```

But the problem is that my server is going off line if i use in at this so many queries

And the content of notify.php is described in at this question.

[Notification sytem is slowing down the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287336/notification-sytem-is-slowing-down-the-website)

Comment: This is a second question you have tagged today with PHP and MySQL, but you are still talking about jQuery and AJAX. Could you please pay attention to the tags?

Comment: Four requests within ten seconds shouldn't crash the server. It looks like you've to take a look at your server logs to find out the root cause of this problem.

Comment: @Dharman Dude will you please understand this is a php mysql question only

Comment: Because the page is php and the query is in mysql  this is the continuation of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287336/notification-sytem-is-slowing-down-the-website

Comment: But this question is not about PHP or MySQL problem. You are hurting yourself. If you were to put correct tags in the question i.e. jQuery you might have gotten more response to it.

Comment: @Dharman it is right. Even if you have your data in MySQL or you call a PHP script, your real problem is about javascript, JQuery and Ajax. **This is not a PHP or MYSQL question** and you should tag it correctly so we can help

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't tag a question `Brain` `Biology` because I can't solve it with my brain. Jokes aside, we do not know what's inside your `notify.php` and probably it's the source of the error.